# Como buscar um item da lista e retornar em uma mensagem?

Tags: python, lista

estou iniciando na programação, e estou fazendo um bot no discord
usando python (discord.py)

> preciso criar um comando pra que o bot retorne a disponibilidade das
> frutas dentro da lista.

```
class Frutas(commands.Cog):  # cog 

    def __init__(self, client):  # setup pra cog.
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(aliases=['f'])  # comando para escolher frutas.
    async def fruta(self, ctx, *, fruta):
        responses = [  # frutas disponíveis
            'Maçã vermelha',
            'Maçã verde',
            'Banana amarela'
        ]
        if fruta in responses:  # se a fruta solicitada existe em "responses":
            await ctx.channel.send(responses.index)  # (aqui deveria mandar a fruta correspondente à lista.)
        else:  # se não:
            await ctx.channel.send(f'não temos essa fruta na loja ({fruta})')  # retorne que não temos a fruta.


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Frutas(client))  # cog
```

> com esse código, ele me retorna isso
>
> [image: print do bot]
>
> eu queria colocar !f maçã e fazer o bot identificar a "Maçã vermelha"
> na lista e retornar a mesma como uma mensagem de minha escolha, mas não sei como fazer pra ele identificar isso...

já testei também sem o index, mas aí ele manda a lista com todas as frutas, e eu ainda assim, preciso digitar "!f Maçã vermelha" invés de "!f maçã"

Answer (score 0):

A lógica básica é, assim que o código for chamado ele iterar a lista de possíveis frutas e testar se a fruta alvo é contida na fruta atual.

Pontos importantes:

1. Acentuação e cedilha
   Evitar acentuação, pois `'Maca' in 'Maçã vermelha'` retorna falso, então para contornar isso, talvez seja interessante evitação acentuação e o 'c' com a cedilha
2. Usar o método [.upper()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=upper#str.upper)
   O método `upper()` converte todas as letras da string em UPPERCASE, isso é importante, pois, o `in` é case sensitive, então o código `banana in Banana` retorna falso.

```
frutas = ['MACA VERMELHA', 'MACA VERDE', 'BANANA AMARELA']

frutaAlvo = 'MacA'
resultado = list()

for fruta in frutas:
    if frutaAlvo.upper() in fruta.upper():
        resultado.append(fruta) # Com apenas esse trecho você terá as possíveis repostas.
    #Com o código abaixo salva o index da primeira ocorrência "mínima":
        #indice = frutas.index(fruta)
        #break


print(resultado)
```

---

`Output: ['MACA VERMELHA', 'MACA VERDE']`

Comment: mas como eu transformaria o frutaAlvo na fruta que o usuário escolhe? (!f (fruta)

Comment: A fruta alvo é só uma string de exemplo que eu usei pra explicar o código. Mas, considerando que você tem a string exata que está contida em uma lista de strings, você pode usar listaDeString.index('string'), que vai retornar o índice em que a string está.

Comment: O que eu achei confuso é que na sua pergunta tem dois problemas: Você quer saber como conseguir as possíveis respostas pro input do usuário (já que o input maçã pode ser tanto maçã vermelha quanto verde), e o problema com o índice. Pro primeiro problema, você pode usar o comando break dentro do if caso queira só uma resposta, e pro segunda o comentário anterior.

Comment: Se meu código foi útil, por favor, considere avaliá-lo.

Answer (score 0):

O seu erro mais imediato é que `index` é um método do tipo `list`. Quando você usa `responses.index` como valor para o método `ctx.channel.send(...)`, você está apenas enviando *o método `index`*, e não *uma invocação do método*. Por isso que ele sempre responde com `<built-in method index of list object at ...>`, pois esse é o ponteiro (localização na memória) do método em si.

Seu código, portanto, está funcionando bem; você precisa apenas alterar o valor enviado de volta, de `responses.index` para a mensagem que você quiser retornar, como `f'Aqui está sua {fruta}!'`